# validate age according to date of birth using model in mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have registration form and its  contain date of birth field.

Using calender date picker  its input the value to this field.

these are the steps to insert value for this field

step 1

[image]

step 2

[image]

step 3

[image]

so its taking values in **dd/MM/yyyy** format

This is appearance of **date of birth** field in my **model class**

```
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
```

This is appearance of **date of birth** field in my **view file**

```
   <div class="form-group"> 
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_of_Birth)
        @Html.Label("*", new { id="star" , @class = "requiredFiledCol" })
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_of_Birth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY" , maxlength="100" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_of_Birth)
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want to do client side validation for data of birth field . show error message when input filed is not in this range **100>Age>18**

whats the approach I should take ?

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that will do this. You would need to write you own validation attribute and implement `IClientValidatable`. [This article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) gives a good guide.

Comment: Side note: Your not using `EditorFor()` to generate the HTML5 datepicker so `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` is not necessary (they only apply to `EditorFor()`)

Comment: I hope you are initializing `datepicker` through javascript. Then you will have several options to set `start date` and `end date` so that without any worry to validations you can render your datepicker

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke you're always showing me additional knowledge  ,

Comment: @Chathz, Calculate the minimum and maximum allowed dates in your controller based on today's date, then pass them to the view (using view model or `ViewBag` properties, and then set the datepickers `minDate` and `maxDate` options - e.g. { ..., minDate: @Model.MiinDate, ...}` but this wont give you server side validation so you will need to check again in the POST method and add `ModelState.Errors` as appropriate

Comment: @Chathz. instead of mentioning `yearRange` you have something called `startDate` and `endDate` option in datepicker or `minDate` and `maxDate` which will help you to restrict the date to be selected by setting them to `endDate` or `maxDate` to -18 years from `today` and `startDate` or `minDate` to -100 years from `today`

Comment: @Chathz, You can also use numeric offsets to specify the `minDate` and `MaxDate` values e.g. `{ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" }`. `[Refer documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I'm looking for a client side validation approach

Comment: @Chathz, A custom validation attribute is best (gives you both server side and client side). The easier solution is to set the min and max dates on the datepicker, but then you still have to manually implement server side validation (client side validation is just a bonus - anyone could post whatever they want (using say Firebug) so you must always validate on the server)

Answer (score 15):

Well since you are already using data annotations why not make your own. 
do this:

create a class in an dll that you use or make a new one and at a minimum add the following code to it

```
public class MinimumAgeAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    int _minimumAge;

    public MinimumAgeAttribute(int minimumAge)
    {
      _minimumAge = minimumAge;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(),out date))
        {
            return date.AddYears(_minimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

then in your view model do this:

```
[MinimumAge(18)]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
```

or your web page you will have no issues as the framework(s) you use will pick it up. Without changing the ErrorMessage property in your class you will get something like

> The field "{0}" is not valid.

The {0} is replaced by the property name or display name attribute that you gave the property in your model.

Hope it works for you.

Walter
ps: make sure in the controller you do

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: This looks like the answer, do you know how to add a custom error message with it?

Comment: Well yes, just add it in the same data annotation way as MinimumAgeAttribute inherits from ValidationAttribute you just add it using the .net way via a resource or hard coded string value

Answer (score 3):

I've improved on Walter's answer regarding making your own custom validation.  I've added better error message support. This will allow a better default error message and also allow you to enter your own with better string.Format support. I've also updated the naming schemes. For instance you should add date to the beginning so that you and other developers know that this validation can only be used with DateTime variables similar to how the base StringLengthAttribute is named for strings.

```
public class DateMinimumAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateMinimumAgeAttribute(int minimumAge)
    {
        MinimumAge = minimumAge;
        ErrorMessage = "{0} must be someone at least {1} years of age";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if ((value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date)))
        {
            return date.AddYears(MinimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, MinimumAge);
    }

    public int MinimumAge { get; }
}


[DateMinimumAge(18, ErrorMessage="{0} must be someone at least {1} years of age")]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
```

Comment: This seemed to work but it doesn't allow for a NULL[Date_of_Birth] even though the model says Nullable. It returns false in the ModelState.IsValid part of controller. Is there a way to allow NULL to pass as true to ModelState.IsValid?

Answer (score 1):

a comment asks TroySteven if there is a way to allow null

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (value == null)  //you can just add this condition
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ((value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value, out date)))
    {
        return date.AddYears(MinimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an id for @Html.ValidationMessageFor and @Html.TextBoxFor, then use javascript to validate it.  In your view do something like:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
      $(function () {
         if (document.getElementById("yourTextBoxID").value < 18){
             document.getElementById("yourValidationMessageID").value = "Can't be less than 18 years old :("
            }
       });
    </script>
}
```