# ASP.NET MVC : Model ─ Adding custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Good Day!, I'm having trouble with towards a custom ValidationAttribute for which when I add one which I just copied from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665290/validate-age-according-to-date-of-birth-using-model-in-mvc-4) stackoverflow answer by Mr. [Walter Verhoeven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191659/walter-verhoeven).

My problem is the [Required] attribute is being override or neglected, I don't have any idea of this and tried searching for solutions but to no avail or I maybe have not thought of the right keywords to search for, anyways here's my sample code

Model

```
[Required]
[MinimumAge(18, ErrorMessage = "must be 18 years old or up")]    
[Display(Name = "Birth date")]
public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
```

for new ValidationAttribute

```
public class MinimumAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    int _minimumAge;

    public MinimumAgeAttribute(int minimumAge)
    {
        _minimumAge = minimumAge;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date))
        {
            return date.AddYears(_minimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

the custom ValidationAttribute works like a charm for validating its 18 years of age however if no input is being put (or null) the [Required] attribute doesn't trigger or work but instead it goes to the

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date))
```

in which of course it gives an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", because the 'value' is null.

so basically I wanted to make the two attributes work together. what do I miss?

-Thank you for reading.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────

As per my understanding with regards to Coding And Testuya's explainations

──────────────────────────────────────────────────

[Required] attribute fires but since an error has occurred on the custom attribute the [Required] attributes response is neglected so the solution was Tetsuya's first reply and seconded by Coding

```
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date))
                return date.AddYears(_minimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (Exception) {  }

        return false;
    }
```

Thank you guys for taking this dumb question of mine.

Comment: Try adding null-checking with direct return value e.g. `if (value == null) return false;`, so that `value.ToString()` never executes while value is null or empty.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Yamamoto-kun, I see your point and also have thought of that kind of solution however the problem for this is it overrides other attributes, what if I'll add another attribute let's say StringLength, then RegularExpression into another kind of dataTypes let's say int with this custom ValidationAttribute, then upon (ModelState.IsValid) would the other attributes work? Sorry for my question. I totally don't knkow much

Comment: Are you want to combine all of them like this: `[Required][StringLength(20)][MinimumAge(18)][RegularExpression("regex_pattern_here")] public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }`? I think those attributes are not overriden by custom attribute (you can have both `StringLength` & `RegularExpression` on same property).

Comment: Oh i see, so you mean that the [Required] Attribute is overridden with my custom attribute? well, because it doesn't trigger when I leave the input blank, is that correct?

Comment: All the attributes will be executed and therefore just because you have `Required` does not mean the rest of the attributes will not. So either handle those cases or check the errors in the modelstate and if required has faliled then return right away from minimumage for example.

Comment: There are no overriden attributes, all attributes are joined together as in model binding and evaluated as such. `RequiredAttribute` checks if the property is null or empty - it is unrelated with `MinimumAgeAttribute` which uses different validation rule (the evaluated property value should be 18 or above).

Comment: Thank you for your answers CodingYoshi & TetsuyaYamamoto. Yes I've understand your points now. I must've focused too much that either one of when will trigger first especially the [Required] attribute and thats it. but all of them works and the one that returns the error is the custom attribute therefore the response from [Required] attribute is neglected,. Thank You so much for your efforts on explaining. Thank you

Comment: Your don't even need your `[Required]` attribute - the property is `DateTime` (not nullable) so its required by default. And you should be checking if `value` is `null` letting an exception occur and catching it.

Comment: Please add your answer as an *answer* to the question and mark it as accepted so others can see this question is resolved. There are no dumb questions as long as they are helpful to others.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I thought mate that the [Required] attribute will fire first giving its response without needing to execute the custom attribute, Sorry for this.

Comment: You only need it if you want to add a specific error message - e.g. `[Required(ErrorMessage = "......")]`. But its good practice to make you property nullable and add the attribute anyway as described in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575)

Comment: @NightOwl888 : Ok mate, have done it, I hope it's clear... Thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I see, Thank you for your thorough explanation mate. This helps me a lot on understanding [Required] attribute, didn't now about that under-posting attack. very well said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

──────────────────────────────────────────────────

As per my understanding with regards to Coding And Testuya's explainations

──────────────────────────────────────────────────

[Required] attribute fires but since an error has occurred on the custom attribute the [Required] attributes response is neglected so the solution was Tetsuya's first reply and seconded by Coding.

So basically, I just have to check the 'object value' if it has a value in it and if none we could just return false, there are many ways to check and return one so below this is how I do it. then afterwards the [Required] attribute gives its response to ValidationMessage since the custom attribute doesn't handle the null value of our value object variable.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    DateTime date;
    try
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out date))
            return date.AddYears(_minimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }

    return false;
}
```

Thank you guys for taking this dumb question of mine.