# Date validation in asp.net mvc code first aproach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to make a validation on my model class for date, I want the validation to restrict user whose age is under 18 gives a error message like your age doesn't meet the requirements, the date is in calendar format so any irregular selection of year like 02/02/9999 also must throw an error by using validation can anyone help me out on this by using any sort of regex?

code:

```
   public class AdmissionModel
   {
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Std_id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public string std_name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public string std_father { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public string std_mother { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     public string DOB { get; set; }      ---This is the date--
   }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665290/validate-age-according-to-date-of-birth-using-model-in-mvc-4

Comment: use fluent validation api. it has everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can validate your date like this

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```